# Quartz Composer in iOS

Tags: ios5, quartz-composer

I am new to iOS platform. Is there anyway I can use quartz composer library embedded into my iPhone app? e.g I would like to get RGBA from a particular pixel from an image (UIImage) using IMAGE PIXEL. [get-color-image-pixel](http://quartzcomposer.nodepond.com/post/4988188682/get-color-image-pixel)

OR can i use existing framework in xcode4 to achieve above scenario??? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Quartz Composer framework does not exist on iOS.

To extract pixel color data from a UIImage, see this question: [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Comment: thanks.. i used  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)'s codes for my app...

Answer (score 2):

Have a see [Quartz Composer for iOS](https://github.com/kluivers/qc-mobile). That runtime implementation for iOS. This project makes it possible to load, display and interact with .qtz files on iOS.

Good luck